# save end of line to data base

Tags: c#, mysql, string

C#

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString); 
string command = "update `triggers` set tri_webbot=@text where `triggers`.TRI_UID='" + TRI_UID + "'";
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(command, connection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);
myCommand.Connection.Open();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myCommand.Connection.Close();
connection.Close();
```

Text

```
test 
    test
        test
```

when run query text save to field database as 'testtesttest' and does not save end of line and space.

but when i do not use parameters and update field with this

```
commad='update `triggers` set tri_webbot="test test test" where `triggers`.TRI_UID='" + TRI_UID + "''
```

everything is correct

**Questino**
how can save space and EOF(end of line) to database field?

Comment: I suspect that `text` is not correct.

Comment: no when do not use parameters sql saved text with space and eof

Answer (score 0):

you should add to your text string "\r\n" or Environment.NewLine
this way you will have end of line and instead of space use newline